# How do I stop the screensaver from coming on during VLC movie watching?

Tags: vlc, screensaver

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and my screensaver keeps coming on while I'm watching a movie.  I don't remember this happening in 11.04 and can't remember how to stop it?

Answer (score 13):

1. Open VLC Media player and go to **Tools -> Preferences** *(Shortcut key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>)*
2. Select **All** from *Show settings* in the bottom-left corner of the Preferences window .
3. Now click the Video Tab on the side.
4. Now *tick* the **Disable Screensaver** box and click save.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work.  The 'Disable Screensaver' box is already checked.

Comment: Fixed in 2.2.0-rc1, VLC now uses dbus to communicate screensaving.

Comment: still does not work in vlc 2.2.6 + LXDE

Answer (score 5):

Another solution but not what you want is:

Open the terminal and type:

`xset s off`

This will disable the screensaver.

to enable it again

`xset s on`

---

There are other options such as disabling for a period of time etc..

Type `man xset` in the terminal for more info

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this happening with VLC as well as Banshee.  The only solution I could find is to run Caffeine.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

After that, run caffeine, go to its preferences and have it start on login.  It sits in your system tray.  Whenever you then watch a movie, you'll need to click on its system tray icon and select 'disable screensaver'.

It is not the best solution but it is the only one I can see in these early days.

Comment: This worked for now.  You can configure Caffeine to automatically start preventing the screensaver and powersaving whenever a particular program is running. To set this up, just run the program that should inhibit the screensaver, right-click on the Caffeine applet, select “Preferences”, and then click “Add”. You should see a list of all running processes in the pop-up window. Click the name of the program that you started earlier and click “Add”. Close the preferences window.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

From my [answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440321/when-using-vlc-why-does-my-screen-saver-keep-waking-up), you can simply run,

```
echo "disable-screensaver=0" >> ~/.config/vlc/vlcrc
```

For more information see [*"When using VLC, why does my screen saver keep waking up?"*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440321/when-using-vlc-why-does-my-screen-saver-keep-waking-up)

Comment: This has the same effect as the method in [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/69634/22949), doesn't it? (It's no problem if it does -- different answers that work through the same underlying mechanism are totally fine -- but if it is somehow different, then I think it may be best to mention that.)

Comment: I don't think so. My answer does so without using a GUI and I don't have to go digging around options. When the GUI answers stops working, my answer will prevail. =)

Comment: Here is the funny thing: even though I had "Disable screensaver" enabled in the GUI of VLC, I opened up my vlcrc file, and the line was commented out.  I commented it in, saved, started VLC, and VLC is *still* failing to disable the screensaver.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69615/how-do-i-stop-the-screensaver-from-coming-on-during-vlc-movie-watching/69634#276214), one can type

```
xset s on; vlc; xset s off;
```

from a terminal to launch vlc, or write a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
xset s on; vlc; xset s off;
```

or a desktop file whose command is something like

```
set s on; vlc %U; xset s off;
```

and set the association file/mimetype to it to open appropriate mimetypes.
"%U" works for TDE, for other desktops, you might need to find the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using xscreensaver and the GUI options do not help, you can use the following funciton to run VLC from the command line:

```
vlc() { xscreensaver-command -exit; command vlc "$@"; nohup xscreensaver -no-splash }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a script which can close xscreensaver when VLC is open, and even closes redshift (eye protector app) when it exists.

You can try it from here:
[Close-Screensaver-Redshift-when-VLC-opened-Script](https://github.com/Pucur/Close-Screensaver-Redshift-when-VLC-opened-Script)